# Wasn't this comment rude?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

I flagged the following [comment](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8653/are-photos-with-rounded-corners-ok-for-us-passports#comment13511_8654) as rude, and the flag got declined. Wasn't this comment implicitly calling the OP "smart-ass" rude?

> One thing I found is that playing smart-ass with USCIS is just asking for trouble.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I declined the flag. I read the comment and decided that while it pushes the limits of *be nice* that it provides enough value that I decided to keep it. As I think you know, there is a fine line between censoring comments via deletion and maintaining a welcoming community.

In retrospect, at a minimum, instead of declining the flag, I should have marked the flag as helpful (even while keeping the comment). In reviewing the comment, I have now edited the useful information (in a nicer format) into the answer.